# Protocol associated types and generics

Tags: ios, generics, swift2

My code looks like this:

```
protocol Remotable {
    init?(dict: Dictionary<String, String>)
}

protocol SearchResultable {
    associatedtype TRS: Remotable
    static func myFunction(remote: TRS)
}

struct MySearchResult<T:SearchResultable, TR: Remotable> {
    typealias TRS = TR
    let items: Array<T>
    let limit: Int

    func testMethod() {
        let dict = [["id": "asd123"],["id":"asd456"]]
        let a = dict.flatMap(TRS.init)
        let b = a[0] //has type TR
        let c = T.myFunction(... //expects an argument of type T.TRS
    }
}
```

And I cannot get to call myFunction because it expects a T.TRS type of argument. I was expecting that I can call myFunction with the b parameter that is of type TR. Do you have any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found an answer to my own question. I don't know which one is better, I would be grateful if someone would explain which is better and why.

```
struct MySearchResult<T:SearchResultable, TR where T.TRS == TR > {
    let items: Array<T>
    let limit: Int

    func testMethod() {
        let dict = [["id": "asd123"],["id":"asd456"]]
        let a = dict.flatMap(TR.init)
        let b = a[0]
        let c = T.myFunction(b)
    }
}
```

So I just had to tell the compiler that T.TRS is the same as TR.

Comment: Your answer is correct because you are introducing two generic types `T` and `TR`, but beyond simply conforming to their respective protocols, you are saying that `TR` is `T`'s `associatedtype`. This relationship between them is what is missing in the code in your question. Well done! +1

Comment: Also, you do not need to constrain `TR` to `Remotable`, this is inferred from the subsequent equality - i.e. this is sufficient: `struct MySearchResult <T: SearchResultable, TR where TR == T.TRS >`

Comment: Thanks Milos for your explanation.

Comment: `where T.TRS == TR` is a type constraint that says they are of the same type, while T.TRS will definitely conform to `Remotable`, so does `TR`.

Comment: @milos Is it possible to allow `TR` to be a subset of `T.TRS`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force unwrap `a[0]` as the function expects an argument of type `T.TRS`, you are sure that `a[0]` will conform to protocol `Remotable`.

```
let c = a[0] as! T.TRS
T.myFunction(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's working but I'm just not a big fan of force unwrapping.